# Is matrix elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem quantum-safe?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

I can't be the first one to think of this and there must be a reason nobody design cryptosystem off this problem.

Let's define MECC as matrix of elliptic curve points, and MI as matrix of non-negative integers.

Given a MECC $G$, MI $v$, and MECC $P=v\cdot G$. How would a quantum computer calculate $v$ from $P$ and $G$?

Comment: How is $\cdot$ defined in the question? As element-wise multiplication or as a matrix-matrix product?

Comment: matrix-matrix product obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasoned it through just now. Given the ultimate generator of the elliptic curve group $G'$

1. Shor $G$ element-wise to obtain an MI $H$ such that $G=H * (G')$, where $*$ is element-wise multiplication.
2. Shor $P$ element-wise against $(G')$ to obtain an MI $J$
3. Calculate $J\over H$ using Gaussian elimination to obtain $v$

Yeah! I defeated myself in a cryptanalysis challenge.

Comment: Was about to say that in a comment. You could consider accepting your own answer then, can be useful if anyone wonders something similar in the future :)